# Where do I find ssh_key_ids for the Digital Ocean Ansible module?

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean

I'm using the [digital ocean module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/digital_ocean_module.html) for Ansible to create droplets.

I need to use the SSH key of my development machine as I already have this key added to my Digital Ocean account. On the man page for the DO module I can't see any way to do this except to use the `ssh_key_ids` option.

What is the `ssh_key_ids` and where do I get the ID from?

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is wondering the v2 API allows you to do this:

```
digital_ocean:
          state: present
          command: droplet
          name: node-app
          ssh_key_ids:
            - "da:5f:1c:f0:72:d5:86:ff:64:03:04:22:46:2f:c3:23"
```

You can get the key from the "Security" page.